# Taking out n rows when total rows are < n

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table says, menu. In which only 5 records are available, but I need more than 5 records including duplication.

Actual scenario, a group of people can order the same menu for example If I have

```
1)tea

   ->foo

   ->bar

2)coffee

   ->latte

   ->expresso

3)shake
```

two or more people can order for coffee.

I tried to do this

```
$menu = RestaurantsMenu::where('tag','=','Coffee')
                                ->get()
                                ->random(5);
```

<kbd>menu</kbd>      
<kbd>tag</kbd>      
<kbd>menu 1</kbd>      <kbd>Chicken</kbd>      
<kbd>menu 2</kbd>      <kbd>vegen</kbd>      
<kbd>menu 3</kbd>      <kbd>Chicken</kbd>

AS you can see I have two types of chicken , If I want to take out 4 chicken randomly, including duplication how can I do it? Please advice.

Comment: share sample table data and expected output that will help to solve the problem

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin PLease check the question, I have added table

Comment: @Rehan I should have asked that rather than interpreting, as it seems like I interpreted wrong. Good lesson.

Comment: @KenColton , 
 if you have less than X rows in DB, how can you create a result set of `X+n` entries by randomly duplicating other rows. This is what I needed, never mind.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, `RestaurantsMenu::inRandomOrder()->limit(5)->get()` should work.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter, what if,there is only 2 rows in total in the table.

Comment: You need a count of the records first. `$count = RestaurantsMenu::count()`. Then pass in `$count` instead of `5`.

Answer (score 0):

**The question was updated while writing and my interpretation of problem may be incorrect - leaving it for now**

Original interpretation: if you have less than X rows in DB, how can you create a result set with X entries by randomly duplicating other rows.

---

**Original answer:**

This kind of duplication should be done just with PHP after you've queried the data you do have.

I would go with a function that takes the query, and the number of results necessary and then randomly create enough rows from existing ones.

```
function fillResultsWithDuplicates($query, $numRowsNeeded) {
  // avoid querying _more_ than needed when you have sufficient
  $res = $query->random($numRowsNeeded); 

  // may need to coerce into an array - not familiar with laravel
  return fillArrayWithRandomDuplicates($res, $numRowsNeeded);
}  

function fillArrayWithRandomDuplicates($vals, $numEntriesNeeded) {
  /*im sure this can be written to be faster and more succinct
  could accept an optional function to perform the filling*/
  if (count($vals) >= $numEntriesNeeded) return $vals;
  $numDuplicatesNeeded = $numEntriesNeeded - count($vals);
  $dupes = [];

  // Here your are pulling random values from your array to act as duplicates needed
  for ($i = 0; $i < $numDuplicatesNeeded; $i++) {
      $dupes[] = $vals[mt_rand(0, count($vals)-1)]; // array_rand could be used as well but may be slower
  }

  // Maybe shuffle as well if you need
  return array_merge($dupes, $vals);
}
```

Usage in your case

```
$menu = RestaurantsMenu::where('tag','=','Coffee')->get()
$filledMenu = fillResultsWithDuplicates($menu, 5);
```

Demo using simple array:

```
$initial = ["a", "b", "c"];
$filled = fillArrayWithRandomDuplicates($initial, 10);
// will contain 7 random selections of a,b,c followed by original a,b,c for total 10 entries
// ex: bcaaabaabc - add shuffles as needed
```

Comment: It's been about 6 years since i've used PHP on the regular so there may be newer shortcuts for some of the operations or overall more succinct approaches. But this is at least compatible with PHP5 (and up) :P

Comment: The question seems to have changed while writing and my interpretation of problem seems incorrect. Oops ... i guess